# Select random img in a cell of a table and print on it with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, frontend

Problem: I've to print an image on an arbitrary(the coordinates of this element will be random generated) image inside of a cell, without overwriting the existing content.

Restriction: I've to think that in a secondary moment I've to move this printed image like a chess game, plus I can use only Javascript or jQuery.

This is the link to the pen: ---> [codepen](https://codepen.io/legeo/pen/MqYarz)

Now, with this functions I set the random coordinates and I know if a cell is walkable or not.

```
function coordinate(){

    let rowCoord= map.length;
    let cellCoord = map[1].length;

    let coord = {
        row: Math.floor(Math.random() * rowCoord),
        cell: Math.floor(Math.random() * cellCoord)
    }

    return coord;  
};


function placeCharAndItem(){
    let coord= coordinate();

    // with this if you choose a walkable table to spawn, this is random generated
    if(map[coord.row][coord.cell] === 0){
        alert(map[coord.rowCoord][coord.cellCoord]);
        place(coord);
    }
    else{
        placeCharAndItem();
    }
};
```

And this is the function where I generate the table:

```
function mapGenerate(){
    var map=createMap(); //the function createMap generates a 2dArray full of 1 and 0.
        //loop the 2d array map and change the number with the appropriate img    
        for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            var innerArrayLength = map[i].length;
            for(var j = 0; j<innerArrayLength; j++){
                if(map[i][j] === 0){
                    map[i][j]="<img class=\"walkable\" src=\"https://image.ibb.co/bGanFz/floor_Resized.png\">";
                }else{
                    map[i][j]="<img class=\"nonWalkable\" src=\"https://image.ibb.co/m9s1az/volcanoresize.png\">";
                }    
                ;
            }
        $("#tableGame").append("<tr><td>"+ map[i].join('') + "<td></tr>")
    }  
}
```

Any kind of help is really appreciated.

this is the result that i need to achieve, probably this image will be better than my words :).

You can ignore the red square and the red line, they are just to highlight that the character is in this random img, inside a td
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSsx9.jpg)

---

Comment: And what's the problem? I don't understand where you need help.

Comment: I try to explain better: i need to select the spawn point for a character in this little game, i was thinking to use the coordinates of the image inside the td. this span point will not be an unwalkable cell. 
Now, i've generated the 2 random number but i don't know how to link them to the right image in the table and let the image character spawn on this cell. 

for example: 

rowCoord = 3 
cellCoord = 2

the character image has to spawn in the 2 image that we find in the 3rd row. I hope i was clear enough

Really thank you for this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I really understand your issue, but by looking at your pen I've written this function, hope it helps:

```
function place(coord, char){
  var charImage = $("<img>").attr("src", char.image).addClass('char');
  var row = $($("#tableGame tr")[coord.row]);
  var cell = $($("td", row)[coord.cell]);
  cell.append(charImage);
}
```

Your map is not being built the way you expect since there are lots of images in a single table cell. Here is how to put an image inside each cell:

```
function mapGenerate(){
  ...
  $("#tableGame").append("<tr><td>"+ map[i].join('</td><td>') + "</td></tr>")
  ...
}
```

https://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/qMEVZz?editors=0010

Comment: unluckly it doesn't works. I understand that I didn't exaplain in the right way, so i added an image to show what i've to do. 
Thank you the same for the interest and for the answer that you gave to me :)

Comment: From the image I can tell the code is doing what you expect. You just need to add some style to the image so it appears on the map. I think your map is not being built the way you expect since there are lots of images in a single table cell.

Comment: I updated the codepen map generation and I styled the image for you. Check it out.

Comment: I want to thank you for all the explanations about the image and how to use properly the td, without have a lot of images in a single cell.

Comment: You are welcome! And if you need any kind of help, or just to chat about javascript game dev, hit me at discord https://discord.gg/a4TwjAR